# Save mysql query result into same database table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Trying to calculate the time difference between current time and the user's settime to get results in minutes and it works, but is there a way to save the same result into table column on the latest row?

```
SELECT settime, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), settime)AS timeleft 
FROM feedtime
```

[image]
On the left side image, it shows result "timeleft" correctly but also an error `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.` Where as my id column is already set as primary, unique and auto_increment

Is there a way i could take the result and update into right side image shown column as timeleft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE feedtime
SET timeleft = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), settime);
```

Note that MySQL may insist that you add a `WHERE` clause which uses a condition on the `id` column, e.g.

```
UPDATE feedtime
SET timeleft = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), settime)
WHERE id = 1;
```

Even if MySQL does not require this, you still might want to add a `WHERE` clause to limit the scope of the update.

Comment: Thanks it worked, i was trying `INSERT INTO feedtime` instead of `UPDATE` as you said